# How to replace all html tags from <anything> to \n<anything>\n [using regexp (JavaScript)]

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace all HTML tags from `<anything>` to `\n<anything>` and `</anything>` to `<anything>\n`

```
var text = "<anything>welcome</anything><anything>Hello</anything>";
```

result

```
var text = "\n<anything>welcome</anything>\n\n<anything>Hello</anything>\n";
```

This code will help you (match all tags)

```
</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen to self-closing tags?

Comment: Why can't you traverse the DOM tree and add those `\n`? Regex is not a great tool for this.

Comment: @faressoft: Also your first result includes a blank line, but your second result doesn't. Which do you want?

Comment: definitely use jQuery. It can do all sorts of magical things like manipulating xml with regex :P

Comment: I think it's a good idea to suggest cleaner approach to the person asking a question but we must not presume anything about the context unless clearly specified. Who knows? It may be for debugging purposes.

Comment: @faressoft, i think @klez is messing with you. http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png

Comment: hahaha @Abe Miessler you are funny, nice image

Comment: @Abe Miessler, yes, I couldn't find that image, but with my comment I was thinking about it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/<(\/?)[a-zA-Z]+(?:[^>"']+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/g, function($0, $1) {
    return $1 === "/" ? $0+"\n" : "\n"+$0;
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can prettify xml without regex:

```
var text = "<anything>welcome</anything><anything>Hello</anything>";
var xml = new XML("<root>" + text + "</root>");
console.log(xml.children().toXMLString());
```

output:

> `<anything>welcome</anything>`
>   `<anything>Hello</anything>`

Comment: @faressoft `var text1 = xml.children().toXMLString();`

Comment: @Abe Ya, the string should give a valid xml when enclosed in the root tag.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't parse HTML using regex. Read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

In JavaScript, you can turn HTML into DOM using the `.innerHTML` property, and after that you can use other DOM methods to traverse it.

Simple example (needs Firebug):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var html = '<p>foo <span>bar</span><br /></p>';
div.innerHTML = html;

function scan(node, depth) 
{
    depth = depth || 0;
    var is_tag = node.nodeType == 1; 
    var self_contained = false;
    if (is_tag) {
        self_contained = node.childNodes.length == 0;
        var tag_name = node.tagName.toLowerCase();
        console.log('<' + tag_name + (self_contained ? ' /' : '') + '>', depth);
    } else {
        console.log(node.data); 
    }
    for (var i = 0, n = node.childNodes.length; i < n; i++) {
        scan(node.childNodes[i], depth + 1);
    }
    if (!self_contained && is_tag) {
        console.log('</' + tag_name + '>', depth);
    }
}

scan(div);
```

Output:

```
<div> 0
<p> 1
foo
<span> 2
bar
</span> 2
<br /> 2
</p> 1
</div> 0
```

You could also modify this to output attributes and use the depth argument for indentation.

Comment: Beat me to it. I don't necessarily agree with the article, but everyone should read it.

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a method but a property.

Comment: Right, thanks. I've been using jQuery's `.html()` for so long that I forget.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Amarghosh's answer:

Assuming the HTML you are trying to parse is more complicated than your example (which I would guess it is) you may want to convert your HTML page into XHTML.  This will allow you to use treat it as XML and do a number of things including:

- Use an XSL to transform the data
- Use .NET's extensive set of XML
  libraries to extract and manipulate the data.

I have done this in the past with a free .NET library called [SGML](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030317.asp).

Answer (score -1):

```
text = text.replace(/<(?!\/)/g, "\n<"); // replace every < (which are not followed by /) by \n<
```